# How can I keep my clock widget work in background?

Tags: task-management

I use clock widgets. The problem is that when I lock the phone, all applications are killed (except some system applications) including clock widgets. When I unlock my phone then I see that clock widget is stuck on time when I locked phone. I have to restart widget. Please tell me that how can I keep my clock widgets work in background without being killed when the phone is locked.

Comment: Why are all the apps getting killed in the first place?  Solve that problem first.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. Apps shouldn't get killed when you're locking your phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem is solved. Following link helped me.

http://support.meetviva.com/knowledge_base/topics/huawei-how-to-disable-battery-optimisation-for-the-viva-app#

I opened Phone Manager, then Power saving, then Protected apps and then I turned on the apps which I do not want to close after turning off my screen.